# Get the EC2 Id create by terraform and use it in a python script for the lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform

With terraform I want to create an EC2 and a lambda. The lambda will be use to start and stop this EC2. But to start the EC2 with a lambda I need a script where I specify the id of this instance.
How can I extract the id the instance I create and add it to my python script ?

Create the instance:

```
resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-0ed752ea0f62749af"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "Instance_test"
  }
}
```

The lambda:

```
# GET AND CONVERT PYTON FILE TO ZIP
data "archive_file" "zipit_lambda_start" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "index_lambda_start.py"
  output_path = "lambda_function_start.zip"
}
# GET THE ROLE 
module "role" {
source = "../IAM_POLICY_IAM_ROLE"
}
#CREATE LAMBDA
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_start_ec2" {
  filename                       = "lambda_function_start.zip"
  function_name                  = "StartEC2Instance"
  role                           = module.role.role_lambda_test_arn
  handler                        = "index.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.zipit_lambda_start.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime                        = "python3.9"
  timeout                        = 10
}
```

The python script export to the lambda to start the EC2:

```
import boto3
region = 'eu-west-1'
instances = ['i-0e6**********c3']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('started your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

[image]

Comment: You could create another function in Python which would fetch the IDs you need using boto3, e.g., https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_instances.html.

Comment: I could try this, but I'm trying to only do it with terraform.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood that it was the Lambda python code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve my problem by using the resource [template file](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile):

First, export the instance Id as an Output:

- `EC2/main.tf`:

```
output "instance_id" {
  value = aws_instance.app_server.id
}
```

- In `Lambda/main.tf`, get the instance id with a module then add a resource made to create a python file from another file with variables as inputs. In this case the only input is `instance_id`.

```
#GET THE EC2
module "ec2" {
source = "../EC2"
}

resource "local_file" "lambda_function" {
  content  = templatefile("${path.module}/index_lambda.py.tpl", { 
                                                                instance_id = module.ec2.instance_id
                                                                })
  filename = "${path.module}/index.py"
}
# GET AND CONVERT PYTON FILE TO ZIP   utiliser template file 
data "archive_file" "zipit_lambda_start" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = local_file.lambda_function.filename
  output_path = "index.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_start_ec2" {
  filename                       = data.archive_file.zipit_lambda_start.output_path
  function_name                  = "StartEC2Instance"
  role                           = module.role.role_lambda_test_arn
  handler                        = "index.lambda_handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.zipit_lambda_start.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime                        = "python3.9"
```

- Now create the file for the source code, `index_lambda.py.tpl`, with our variable being `instance_id`:

```
import boto3

region = 'eu-west-1'
instances = ["${instance_id}"]
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('started your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

I am able to create lambda index code with id of the EC2 created before.

Comment: No, using a template file is certainly the wrong approach for code.

Comment: Why ?  ` ` ` ` `

Comment: Because it might be quite likely that that pattern appears in the code or you incorrectly replace stuff. Additionally my suggested way is the best practice and works, period. Not sure why you did not get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `environment` of the lambda to pass in the `id` of the instance:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_start_ec2" {
  // everything as before
  environment {
    variables = {
      INSTANCE_ID = aws_instance.app_server.id
    }
  }
}
```

and then use `os.environ['INSTANCE_ID']` to get it back from the environment.

Comment: I will also take the id when I convert my python file to zip whit data "archive file" ".."{type=zip ...} ? (see my edit)

Comment: @user15915737 I don't understand what you mean - it does not matter how or where you zip your lambda code as long as you pass the variable to the lambda and the code uses that variable.

Comment: The code export to my lambda don't contain the id but the `os.environ['INSTANCE_ID']`  (see my edit)

Comment: Just add it as a list element instead of doing the assignment like you are doing right now.

Comment: You mean like this : `instances = [os.environ['INSTANCE_ID']]`?

Comment: still doesn't work